# Run polymer automatic tests on Windows Edge browser

Tags: polymer, automated-tests, microsoft-edge, polymer-2.x, web-component-tester

I've created an application using polymer 2 and polymer-cli:

https://github.com/jfcorugedo/polymer-timer-manager

I've coded some tests using polymer capabilities.

When I run the tests on MacOS, everything goes right. `web-component-tester` locates my browsers (chrome and safari) and runs all the tests.

The problem comes when I try to run my tests on Windows.

When I run the tests on Windows 10 and Microsoft Edge 38.14393.1066.0, `web-component-tester` can't find my edge installation. It runs the tests on chrome, firefox and IE11, but not edge.

If fact I've tried to point wtc to edge but it doesn't work:

```
> polymer test -l edge

Error: The following browsers are unsupported: edge. (All supported browsers: aurora, canary, chrome, firefox, ie)
```

It seems to my that I can't run automated tests on edge using wtc.

How can I run my wtc tests on Windows Edge browser?